# Strange issue when trying to upload images

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, image-uploading

Working on building a custom upload form (viewable on front end to logged in users) that will upload images (and images only) straight to the wordpress media library (NOTE: do not want it immediately added to a specific post id) ... but am running into an issue I can't seem to fix.

When a user logs in to the custom page they're presented with an upload form ... after selecting the photo(s) that they want to upload (using wp default upload limit parameters ... being `upload_max_filesize 32M / max_file_uploads 20`) and click the `upload` button the form redirects to the upload script `upload.php` (redirecting is for testing purposes only); now, here's the issue ... at the top of my upload script (just after including the required wp files) I dump the `$_FILES` array which, without running anything in the rest of the script returns the following:

```
array(1) { ["photos"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } 
["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> 
string(0) "" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(4) } ["size"]=> array(1) 
{ [0]=> int(0) } } }
```

So, I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong in my form or the like ... because like I said it's not my upload script since it's not even completing it's run.

**Here's my code**

HTML form (yes, as you can see I'm using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in my form)

```
<form id="photo-upload" method="POST" action="<?php echo plugins_url( 'photo-uploadr/templates/upload.php' ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">                        

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="33554432" />
    <input type="file" id="file-upload" name="photos[]" multiple />
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="pick-photos"><?php _e( "Select Photos to Upload", "shorti" ); ?></button>

    <ul id="file-uploads">
        <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
    </ul>

    <button name="upload" id="upload" class="btn upload"><?php _e("Upload", "shorti"); ?></button>

</form>
```

JS (this is what deals with making "#pick-photos" click "#file-upload")

```
jQuery('#pick-photos').click(function() {
    jQuery('#file-upload').click();
});
```

PHP upload script upload.php (only the parts that are getting run)

```
<?php
// "/wordpress" added in front because of local host's DOCUMENT_ROOT being one directory short
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wordpress/wp-load.php" );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/media.php" );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/file.php" );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/image.php" );

print_r( $_POST ); // Dumps the value of "MAX_FILE_SIZE"
var_dump( $_FILES );

if ( !$_FILES ) exit;

// Required for the wp_handle_upload() to upload the files
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$logged_in_user = $current_user->ID;

// load up a variable with the upload directory
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
var_dump( $uploads );
/** Since I'm doing this on localhost I figured I should add what this is returning
*
* array(6) { ["path"]=> string(62) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/01" 
* ["url"]=> string(58) "http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/01"
* ["subdir"]=> string(8) "/2014/01" 
* ["basedir"]=> string(54) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/uploads" 
* ["baseurl"]=> string(50) "http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads" 
* ["error"]=> bool(false) }
*/


foreach ( $_FILES['photos']['error'] as $key => $error ) {
    if ( $error === UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) { // Not passing here because $_FILES is receiving error #4
```

When I checked permissions like so:

```
cd /Applications/MAMP
ls -la
```

This is what it said `drwxrwxr-x` in regard to the tmp directory

Hoping and praying that someone knows how to fix this ... thanks for your time and any help! :)

Comment: When you say `redirects to the upload script upload.php (redirecting is for testing purposes only)` what do you mean by that?

Comment: @SetSailMedia I mean that I have the form `action` parameter set so that it redirects for debugging purposes ... but, it will be handled by ajax once everything is working. Sorry for not being clear on that.

Comment: Does it work with one small file, say just a few KB? Interesting that it's built the array for you knowing there are submissions. Somehow the file isn't being written to the temp folder. Can you use `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in a blank file, accessed from a browser, to see PHP's configuration for `file_uploads`, `max_file_uploads`, `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize` and `memory_limit`

Comment: And, if you put the `print_r()` above the includes, any change? I wonder if some WordPress include isn't eating up the variable and doing something with it.

Comment: Is your local machine Windows or Linux? May be a misconfiguration with PHP handling file uploads if Windows.

Comment: @SetSailMedia first, file_uploads: ON, max_file_uploads: 20, post_max_size: 32M, upload_max_filesize: 32M, memory_limit: 32M ... second, using `print_r()` returns the same error ... and thirdly, I'm using a mac (so a unix system). Hope this helps!

Comment: @SetSailMedia also, I tried uploading just one file that was `289.40KB` and still got nothing.

Comment: Well, paint me perplexed! I don't see any obvious problem. Do you have another machine/environment that can be tested on?

Comment: @SetSailMedia you'll be able to tell I'm new to this type of thing after you read this ... just had a friend do some testing and said that my JS (more than what I added here) was responsible! Thanks for your help, I will now know how to debug normal uploader issues! Sorry for the confusion. ;)